# Will a privately registered domain become public if it is in dispute?

Tags: domains

We registered a domain privately. The domain was recently disputed

Comment: What type of dispute, do you mean a [UDRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Domain-Name_Dispute-Resolution_Policy)? If so, both parties (the domain registrant and the complainant) will be listed in the WIPO case for the purposes of notification, trademark verification, and supporting documentation. Cases are [publicly searchable](https://www.wipo.int/amc/en/center/faq/domains.html#17) in their database after the parties have been notified of the final decision, which Google does crawl. So eventually the domain registrant will become public if searched for.

Comment: Maybe. It depends on the domain, the TLD, the registrar, the dispute. If you gave the domain name you could have elicited useful replies. Start by reading again the contract you signed with your registrar and the parts about the "private registration" to see what happens in case of disputes. If it is a gTLD, it will be bound by ICANN regulations on privacy & proxy services at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/pp-services-2017-08-31-en